# How to send image with ID in Ajax

Tags: ajax

i am trying to send a blob image with ajax, this worked fine. however whenever i try out add another dataset in ajax it stops working. i only receive one. here is my code:

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        var id = new FormData();

        formData.append('avatar', blob);
        id.append('id', '<?php echo $token['token_confirmation']; ?>');

        $.ajax('upload_img.php', {

        method: 'POST',
        data: {formData, id},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
```

Comment: please add your html code

Comment: i fixed the problem, the problem was that the append worked but it sent it over $_FILES AND $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem, the problem was that the append worked but it sent it over $_FILES AND $_POST